# Unable to convert correct device token in swift 3.0

Tags: swift, xcode, push-notification, swift3, xcode8

Using swift 3.0, I am trying to convert a deviceToken (data) to string, but it is not returning the correct string.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

    let tokenString = deviceToken.reduce("") { string, byte in
        string + String(format: "%02X", byte)
    }
    print("token: ", tokenString)

}
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What do you get and what do you expect?

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 3 it's a bit easier because `Data` behaves like an array:

```
let tokenString = deviceToken.map{ String(format: "%02X", $0) }.joined()
```

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, this would give exactly the same result as OP's code which uses that Data is a sequence in Swift 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it using this method as device tokens is an array of UInt8 in the form of bytes you have describe every byte.

```
let token = String(describing: deviceToken as CVarArg).replaceCharacters("<> ", toSeparator: "")
```

I have created extension to String as I use replaceCharacters() frequently

`extension String { 
    func replaceCharacters(_ characters: String, toSeparator: String) -> String {
        let characterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: characters)
        let components = self.components(separatedBy: characterSet)
        let result = components.joined(separator: toSeparator)
        return result
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
 var token = NSData.init(data: deviceToken).description
    token = token.replacingOccurrences(of: "<", with: "")
    token = token.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
    token = token.replacingOccurrences(of: ">", with: "")
    token = String.init(describing: token)

    print(token)
```

Hope this will help you to get exact devicetoken for sending to your server.